# Java: constructors that take .class as arguments

Tags: java, android, constructor

I am an experienced Java developer but I am still unable to wrap my head around constructors that take .class as arguments.

Example(from Android):

```
startActivity(myActivity.class)
```

I am confused about how `myActivity.class` is utilized by the `startActivity()`. Although I can look at the source code of the `startActivity()` to get proper insight, but I am looking for some leads into what kind of pattern it is. Is it somehow related to reflection?

Comment: Use for reflection or generic dynamic instanciation

Comment: Yes it does use reflection

Comment: A simple tutorial on using constructors and reflection http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html

Comment: In java 8 the design might have been more clear with `startActivity(MyActivity::new)` - as reduced as possible to the functionality required. As reflection is not something stylistically desirable in an official pattern, I would call this just "passing class for factory". One sees passing of a class with generics to constructors, to provide run-time information to have methods returning the actual class by Class.cast and creating class instances (because of type-erasure). That would be "providing run-time type information."